# Voice recognition: Cut off interpreter's voice from audio

Tags: voice-recognition, speech

I have several hours of lectures in which consecutive interpretation takes place. ( And I really mean several, it's a huge database ). Consecutive interpretation means that the lecturer speaks a little, and then, after he pauses, the interpreter translates what he has just said to the audience.

The lecturer speaks in English and then the interpreter translates into the local language ( He's giving lectures worldwide so the "local language" could be anything ).

I was charged with the task of cutting off the interpreter's voice from the audio, leaving only the lecturer.

I need some guidance on the easiest way to achieve this goal. I guess it's a quite straightforward task, as there's absolutely no voice overlap between the lecturer and the interpreter.

What's the best tool for this task? Sphinx? Julius? Something else? Please help.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0):

It is called speaker diarization, you can check

http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/quick_start

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.